# Using two light switches to control a single outlet location

Tags: receptacle

Can you take a single outlet and have light switch A switch the top receptacle and light switch B switch the bottom receptacle? I am in the U.S.

Comment: Possible? Yes. Advisable? Not sure. To code? That's the question (which I myself don't have the answer for).

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Assuming power enters at the switch box.  You'll have to run a 3-wire with ground cable between the switch box, and the receptacle.  You'll also have to break the little bonding tab, on the "hot" side of the receptacle.

**At the switch box:**

- Connect the feeder white wire, to the white wire going to the receptacle.
- Using pigtails, connect the feeder black wire, to a terminal on each switch.
- Using pigtails, connect the feeder ground to the receptacle ground wire, and each switch.
- Connect the black wire that goes to the receptacle, to one of the switches.
- Connect the red wire that goes to the receptacle, to the other switch.

**At the receptacle.**

- Connect the white wire to one of the silver colored terminals on the receptacle.
- Connect the ground wire to the green terminal on the receptacle, and the box if it's metal.
- Connect the black wire to one brass colored terminal on the receptacle.
- Break the tab between the brass terminals.
- Connect the red wire to the other brass colored terminal on the receptacle.

---

Here's a diagram showing the wiring when the power is at the switches, and when the power is at the receptacle.

[image]
<sup>*Yellow blobs represent wires in cable/conduit.*</sup>